# Can't find the bug in this JS function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that returns a certain string when an input is within a given set of ranges. Use case: I want to change the color of my webpage based upon the temperature in a given city. I have a function that takes a number and returns one of the color variants. However, it seems to always return "pink". Any help?

```
function colorTemperature(temperature){
      if(temperature <= -10){
        colorTemperatureResult = 'midnightblue';
      }
      if(temperature > 0 && temperature <= 10)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'darkblue';
      }
      if(temperature > 10 && temperature <= 20)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'royalblue';
      }
      if(temperature > 20 && temperature <= 30)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'steelblue';
      }
      if(temperature > 30 && temperature <= 40)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'deepskyblue';
      }
      if(temperature > 40 && temperature <= 50)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'lightblue';
      }
      if(temperature > 50 && temperature <= 60)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'lightyellow';
      }
      if(temperature > 60 && temperature <= 70)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'lemonchiffron';
      }
      if(temperature > 70 && temperature <= 80)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'khaki';
      }
      if(temperature > 80 && temperature <= 90)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'orange';
      }
      if(temperature > 90 && temperature <= 100)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'gold';
      }
      if(temperature >= 100)
      {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'orangered';
      }
      else {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'pink';
      }
      return colorTemperatureResult;
    }
```

Also if there is an easier way to do this functionality without all of these conditionals, please let me know. I know that the input is being passed correctly, but can't figure out in the logic where it is going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code does not address -9 to 0

Comment: The `else` is only bound to the last `if` before it and will only negate that one condition, so it has the same meaning as `if (temperature < 100) { colorTemperatureResult = 'pink'; }`. The `if`s before those are likely working fine, but the `else` follows and replaces the value anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your `if` expressions have an `else if` to prevent them from being evaluated unnecessary if execution continues.

Change your string-assignments from `colorTemperatureResult = 'whatever'` to `return 'whatever'` and it will work.

However your code is unnecessarily complicated, you can also eliminate the `>` comparisons completely:

```
function colorTemperature(temperature) {
  if(temperature <= -10) {
      return 'midnightblue';
  } else if(temperature <= 10) {
      return 'darkblue';
  } else if(temperature <= 20) {
      return 'royalblue';
  } else if(temperature <= 30) {
      return 'steelblue';
  } else if(temperature <= 100) {
  // snip
  } else if(temperature <= 110) {
      return 'gold';
  } else {
      return 'orangered'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else` is referring to the last `if` statement. Just switch all the `if` statements except the first one to `else if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I came by 2 lines solution for you. Check it out:

```
function colorTemperature (temperature) {
  var strings = ['midnightblue', 'darkblue', 'royalblue', 'steelblue', 'deepskyblue', 'lightblue', 'lightyellow', 'lemonchiffron', 'khaki', 'orange', 'gold', 'orangered', 'pink']
  return strings[Math.floor(temperature / 10) + 1] || 'whatever'
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, what do you mean by range? Represent it with object?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you create a global `colorTemperatureResult`
You should create one in the function scope:

```
function colorTemperature(temperature){
    var colorTemperatureResult = "";
    ...
```

One simple method would be to change:

```
 else {
        colorTemperatureResult = 'pink';
      }
```

to check if one is previously assigned:

```
colorTemperatureResult = colorTemperatureResult ? colorTemperatureResult : 'pink';
```

You could also write a simple function:

```
function between(x, min, max) {
  return x > min && x <= max;
}
```

and use it:

```
if(between(temperature,0,10)) {colorTemperatureResult = 'darkblue';}
...
```

**EDIT:** You could also make a generic list of ranges and process from that:

```
var tempMap = {
  default: 'pink',
  ranges: [{
    min: -10,
    max: 0,
    color: 'midnightblue'
  }, {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    color: 'darkblue'
  }, {
    min: 10,
    max: 20,
    color: 'royalblue'
  }, {
    min: 20,
    max: 30,
    color: 'steelblue'
  }, {
    min: 30,
    max: 40,
    color: 'deepskyblue'
  }, {
    min: 40,
    max: 50,
    color: 'lightblue'
  }, {
    min: 50,
    max: 60,
    color: 'lightyellow'
  }, {
    min: 60,
    max: 70,
    color: 'lemonchiffron'
  }, {
    min: 70,
    max: 80,
    color: 'khaki'
  }, {
    min: 80,
    max: 90,
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    min: 90,
    max: 100,
    color: 'gold'
  }, {
    min: 100,
    max: 110,
    color: 'orangered'
  }]
};

function between(x, min, max) {
  return x > min && x <= max;
}

function colorTemperature(temperature) {
  var colorTemperatureResult = "";
  // its really cold out there
  if (temperature < tempMap.ranges[0].min) colorTemperatureResult = tempMap.ranges[0].color;
  else
    for (var i = 0; i < tempMap.ranges.length; i++) {
      if (between(temperature, tempMap.ranges[i].min, tempMap.ranges[i].max)) {
        colorTemperatureResult = tempMap.ranges[i].color;
        break;
      }
    }
  colorTemperatureResult = colorTemperatureResult ? colorTemperatureResult : tempMap.default;
  return colorTemperatureResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question, this would be a simpler approach, while keeping the concept of temperature ranges. It'll also be easier to update the list of colors/temps. You can change out the range delimiter (the forward slash) to whatever you want:

```
var tempColorMap = {
    '-10/0'  : 'midnightblue',
    '1/10'   : 'darkblue',
    '11/20'  : 'royalblue',
    '21/30'  : 'steelblue',
    '31/40'  : 'deepskyblue',
    '41/50'  : 'lightblue',
    '51/60'  : 'lightyellow',
    '61/70'  : 'lemonchiffron',
    '71/80'  : 'khaki',
    '81/90'  : 'orange',
    '91/100' : 'gold',
    '101/500': 'orangered'
};

function getColorByTemp(temp) {
    var color = 'pink';

    for (var range in tempColorMap) {
        var rangeSplit = range.split('/');
        var min        = rangeSplit[0];
        var max        = rangeSplit[1];

        if (temp >= min && temp <= max) {
            color = tempColorMap[range];
            break;
        }
    }

    return color;
}
```

Edit: case typo